# Why does wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' ) work as an argument of wp_enqueue_styles, but not $version = wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' )?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm a little confused. I am making a Wordpress theme and just noticed that the versioning I had implemented in functions.php wasn't actually displaying ?ver in the source code. My original code is this:

```
    //Register styles
$version = wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' );
function cloudbank_register_styles(){
    wp_enqueue_style('cloudbank-style', get_template_directory_uri() . "/style.css", array(), $version, 'all');



}
```

That doesn't work, but this does!

```
function cloudbank_register_styles(){
    wp_enqueue_style('cloudbank-style', get_template_directory_uri() . "/style.css", array(), wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' ), 'all');
```

Am I overlooking something? These look like they should be the exact same thing to me. Why does #2 work, and not #1?

Comment: _“Am I overlooking something?”_ - yes, _variable scope_. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: DANG woops. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It was variable scope the whole time.